# What ECMAScript version is supported by Chrome extensions runtime?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

What ECMAScript version should I target when writing Chrome extension? Is there a page somewhere with that information? Chrome API documentation doesn't seem to provide it.

I only found [this](https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/es6-modules-in-chrome-extensions-an-introduction-313b3fce955b) article from Dec 2017, but of course I don't know what is the current state.

Comment: that's an article about ES6 modules - which is a small small part of ES6

Comment: Sure, I mean that this is the only indication (known to me) of what is supported.

Comment: chrome technically supports 98% of ES6, but 100% of ES5 and interestingly 100% of ES7)

Comment: ES version is actually related to the browser version that you use, not to a extensions API.

Comment: that 2% is "proper tail calls" - which isn't really going to bother you too much - technically, Chrome 68+ supports all of ES2016, 2017, 2018 and even ES2019 - source: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/

Comment: @Deliaz Isn't a version of extensions API tied to version of browser?

Comment: @JaromandaX Ah, so extensions runtime supports the same features as browser itself. This is kinda logical given that extensions are sandboxed pages, but nonetheless would be better to state explicitly somewhere :) Thanks, if you'll make your comment into an answer I'll be able to accept it.

Comment: API of extensions isn't tied to ES/ECMA version. The API is just a set of standard JS objects compatible with all versions of JS supported by Chrome since its very first version e.g. `chrome`, properties, and methods within those objects. As for modules, there were some bugs regarding their implementation inside extension pages but AFAIK they are fixed already.